# Поиск элементов в <select>

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется поиск в списке `<select>`, скрывает все элементы, которые не совпадают с тем, что ввели в поиск. Но есть проблема, при поиске в большом списке (4500 элементов), виснет на пару секунд. Какими еще другими способами можно сделать поиск или оптимизировать?

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    let input = document.getElementById(dataTargetID + 'Input'); 
    let val = input.value.trim().toUpperCase();
    let searchItems = document.querySelectorAll('#'+dataTargetID + ' option');
    if (e.target.classList.contains('keyboard__key')) {
        if (val != '') {
            searchItems.forEach(function (elem){
                if (elem.innerText.toUpperCase().search(val) == -1) {
                    elem.classList.add('hidden')
                }
                else {
                    elem.classList.remove('hidden');
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            searchItems.forEach(function (elem){
                elem.classList.remove('hidden');
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Метод `search` использует регулярки. Судя по коду, ты ищешь подстроку. Юзай или `indexOf` или `includes` думаю должно быть побыстрее..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется это будет быстрее потому что:

- Не нужно каждый раз искать `input` и `searchItems`
- `includes` [быстрее](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296268/fastest-way-to-check-a-string-contain-another-substring-in-javascript) чем `search`
- `for of` [быстрее](https://leanylabs.com/blog/js-forEach-map-reduce-vs-for-for_of/#arrayforeach-vs-for-and-forof) чем `forEach`
- Нет лишних `if else`

```js
// Prepare options (Start)
const select = document.querySelector('#select');
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (let i = 0; i < 4500; ++i) {
  const option = document.createElement('option');
  option.textContent = i + 1;
  
  fragment.append(option);
}

select.append(fragment);

// Prepare options (End)


const input = document.querySelector('#input');
const searchItems = document.querySelectorAll('#select option');

input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  const target = e.target;
  const val = target.value.trim().toUpperCase();

  if (!target.classList.contains('keyboard__key')) return;

  for (const elem of searchItems) {
    const needShow = val !== '' && !elem.textContent.toUpperCase().includes(val);

    elem.classList.toggle('hidden', needShow);
  }
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
}

select {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" class="keyboard__key">
<select id="select" size="20">
</select>
```

Придумал вариант без классов, а через `fragment`-ы. По моим проверкам и онлайн тестам это работает намного быстрее как в FF так и в Chrome.

Если я правильно понял, то это работает быстрее потому что:

- Поиск `option`-ов происходит непосредственно в самом `select`
- Удалять элементы и потом вставлять разом все нужные работает быстрее, чем каждому отдельно навешивать класс (если честно понятия и не имею почему это так, если кто-то объяснит причину буду премного благодарен)

```js
// Prepare options (Start)
const select = document.querySelector('#select');
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (let i = 0; i < 4500; ++i) {
  const option = document.createElement('option');
  option.textContent = i + 1;
  
  fragment.append(option);
}

select.append(fragment);

// Prepare options (End)


const input = document.querySelector('#input');
const searchItems = select.querySelectorAll('option');

input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  const target = e.target;
  const val = target.value.trim().toUpperCase();
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

  if (!target.classList.contains('keyboard__key')) return;
  
  for (const elem of searchItems) {
    elem.remove();
    
    if (val === '' || elem.textContent.toUpperCase().includes(val)) {
      fragment.append(elem);
    }
  }

  select.append(fragment);
})
```

```css
input {
  position: absolute;
}

select {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" class="keyboard__key">
<select id="select" size="20">
</select>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137260/discussion-on-answer-by-eziomercer----select).

Answer (score 1):

Универсальное решение, для нескольких `input` для ввода "запроса" и `select` для поиска.

**JS**:

```
const input = document.querySelectorAll('.search-select');
let cache;

[...input].map(elem => {
  const select = document.querySelector('#'+elem.dataset.for);
  if(select) {
    elem.addEventListener('focus', e => cache = [...document.querySelector('#'+e.target.dataset.for).children);
    elem.addEventListener('input', e => {
      if(e.target.value.length > 0) {
        cache.forEach(el => el.style.display = el.innerText.trim().includes(e.target.value) ? '' : 'none')
      } else cache.forEach(el => el.style.display = '');
    });
  }
})
```

Потестив заметил, что `.forEach` работает быстрее, по этому используется он.
`.includes()` находит любое совпадение в тексте, можно заменить на другое, но может замедлить перебор.

Основное преимущество, как по мне, что при `focus`е `input`а сохраняет содержимое `select`а (по сути все `option`), после перебирает.

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" class="search-select" data-for="select">
<select id="select">
  <!-- ... -->
</select>
```

Связка `input` с `select` схожа с `label` и `input`, JS будет искать `select` с ID который указан в `input[data-for]`.

[Пример работы кода на 4500 option](https://codepen.io/de-minov/pen/YzebLMb)

---

P.s.
Как сравнивал и что.
Взял массив из 4500 `option`, что есть по ссылке выше и прошёлся через некоторые способы:

`.map()` - ~28мс
`.forEach()` - ~6мс
`for()` - ~26мс
`while() i++` - ~21мс
`while(len--)` - ~19мс

Действие при переборе - спрятать элементы с чётным `value`.
[Код теста](https://codepen.io/de-minov/pen/yLvWEgv)

---

Попробовал сделать вариант с `.filter()`, но лучше не становится, наоборот, время выполнения возрастает.

В моём коде используется поиск совпадений по значению, что возвращает `.innerText` из 4500 `option` с `value` и `innerText` равным порядковому числу, поиск совпадений со значением - `1`, занимает ~131мс.
Коллеги советуют заменить поиск по `.innerText`, я попробовал некоторые вариант и вот результаты:

`.innerText` - ~131мс
`.value` - ~20мс
`.innerHTML` - ~26мс
`.textContent` - ~25мс
`.dataset` - ~23мс

У последних четырёх разница не особо заметна, но советуют использовать `.value`.

Comment: В примере работы кода на 4500 option, чуть быстрее конечно, чем у меня. Может можно как-то весь список держать в массиве, а отображать не все сразу, при поиске искать уже из массива?

Comment: По сути весь список уже хранится в массиве, поиск проходит по нему и значения массива используются как адрес, для того, чтобы спрятать элемент. Можно попробовать фильтровать и выводить в `select` только подходящие элементы, но мне кажется, что работа с HTML только замедлит. Я попробую сделать такой вариант и отпишусь по готовности

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, буду ждать

Comment: `innerText` - точно не относится к "правильному" решению.

Comment: Я могу искать и через `.value`, нет конкретного условия `innerText`

Comment: @Qwertiy, о чём вы?

Comment: @De.Minov, `innerText` - самое тормозное свойство, использование которого может раз в 20 всё размедлять.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а как быть? Использовать `.textContent` который и "мусор" потянет за собой?

Comment: Раз это `option`-ы, то думаю было бы намного полезнее использовать их аттрибут `value`. Но я тоже не трогал эту часть в своём ответе, но в целом согласен с @Qwertiy

Comment: @EzioMercer, в value, скорее всего, id. А вот innerText на textContent заменяется элементарно.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну если внутри просто текст, то да `textContent` будет быстрее справляться с задачей. Но раз автор говорит, что ему без разницы как искать, то всё же склоняюсь задействовать `value`

Comment: @Arteil, увы, при `.filter` только хуже, т.к. идёт замена HTML, но дополнил ещё тем, как можно ещё ускорить)